# how to save all the packages installed in conda and move to another computer?

Tags: conda

I know conda has a way to save environment. I have tons of packages installed in current laptop. Is there a way to save a copy of what I have installed in an environment so I can install in another laptop? I know there is some way to save environment and load environment. but how to include all the packages in the saved environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you've never cleaned your tarballs, you can probably just copy them all from `anaconda/pkgs/*.bz2` or `miniconda/pkgs/*.bz2`. Then export each env as a .yaml,

```
conda env export -n yourenv -f yourenv.yaml
```

and recreate on the new machine

```
conda env create -f yourenv.yaml
```

When you create from the .yaml, it'll say whether it needs to download or not, indicating failure or success of the procedure, respectively.

I've never done this, but I think it's worth a try.